# jQuery not().bind('click'); doesn't work

Tags: jquery

```
jQuery('div').not("#supcont").bind('click', function() {
    jQuery("#supcont").slideUp("slow");
});
```

On:

```
jQuery("#supcont").click();
```

Acts like `#supcont` is not exluded. Why?

Comment: Maybe because `#supcont` is inside another `div`. Events bubble up the tree.

Comment: What do you want to do? It acts beautifully! The problem is your way of doing things. Tell us what do you want to do.

Comment: You're going to have to show HTML code for us to debug, but I'm putting my money on @FelixKling's answer.

Comment: This seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/FcDsR/ You need to provide the relevant markup.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for answering. I want to trigger: jQuery("#supcont").slideUp("slow"); onclick anywhere expecting div#supcont.

Comment: please check the syntex of using **not()** here http://api.jquery.com/not-selector

Comment: http://topup-me.com Clicking link "Company" there is going to be slidedown menu. When it activates, area around slided down div should be trigger to slide up menu.

Comment: @punit: `not()` is **not** the problem, and [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector) is not [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not)!

Comment: @punit - Are you saying the syntax for `.not()` in the question is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It [should work fine](http://jsfiddle.net/KrtVu/). The only reason I can think of that it may not, is that your `#supcont` element is a descendant of a `div`, and as the click event will bubble up, the `div` will receive it. To prevent that happening, you can use the `stopPropagation` method of the event object:

```
jQuery('div').not("#supcont").bind('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    jQuery("#supcont").slideUp("slow");
});
```

**Update** (see comments)

Actually, the above won't help you if `#supcont` is a descendant of another `div`, you will need to capture the event on `#supcont` and stop it there. So bind a click event handler to `#supcont` too:

```
jQuery("#supcont").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: You'd have to attach a click event handler to `#supcont` in order to prevent the bubbling. Like this: `$("#supcont").click(false)`. Actually there could be two reasons: Either `#supcont` is inside a `div` or a `div` is inside `#supcont`. You have to consider both.

Comment: Oh, yeah! That's very true. I'm mixing round descendants and ancestors! Updated. (Using `stopPropagation` still in `#supcont` click event handler just for clarity, rather than your suggestion of `.click(false)` which is of course perfectly valid).

Comment: @FelixKling: Isn't `stopPropagation()` sufficient?

Comment: @Eric: If you refer to the original code in this answer, then no, because the click event will still bubble up from `#supcont` to some parent `div`. *Then* the propagation will be stopped and the animation takes place. You really have to add an event handler to `#supcont` and stop the propagation. You'd also have to exclude all descendants of `#supcont`, actually.

Comment: To expand on my other point: You also should not only exclude `#supcont`, but all its descendants. Yes, the event would be prevented from bubbling up, but the animation (`jQuery("#supcont").slideUp("slow");`) would still take place.

Comment: Thank you very much guys. This one did a trick. The my mistake was:  e.stopPropagation();

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding an event to each `<div>` tag on the page , you should add a single event handler on a whole `document`. You should examine the ways to use event delegation and "bubbling".

- http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-event-delegation-is-easier-than-you-think/
- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-javascript-event-delegation-in-4-minutes/

Comment: @JaredFarrish .. i already told you: learn how to use event delegation. You do not need to select ANYTHING to attach the event.

Comment: Well, that didn't come out right. It was meant to agree with you (since that was my first thought when I saw the code).

Answer (score 0):

Another way to write this would be:

```
$('div').click(function() {
    if(!$(this).is('#supcont'))
        $('#supcont').slideUp("slow");
});

$('#supcont').click()
```

Comment: `this` will always refer to the element the handler is bound to. So if `#supcont` is inside a `div` or a `div` inside `#supcont` is clicked, then the animation takes place as well (which is not desired). Changing the test to `if($(event.target).closest('#supcont').length === 0)` should work though. `event.target` refers to the element that was clicked and `closest` will match if the element itself or any ancestor is `#supcont` (this would work with event delegation as well).